# Ошибка запуска в Visual Studio Code

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

При запуске в Visual Studio Code файла index1-1.html, при помощи клавиш Ctrl+F5, в браузере Chrome вышло сообщение:

**http://localhost:8080/
Не удается получить доступ к сайтуСайт localhost не позволяет установить соединение.
Попробуйте сделать следующее:
Проверьте подключение к Интернету.
Проверьте настройки прокси-сервера и брандмауэра.
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**

Так понял дело в launch.json. Скажите как его надо настроить чтобы в IDE запуск html, был без ошибок.

Код index.html:

```
!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>Text</header>
    <section>Text</section>
    <footer>Text</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Код launch.json:

```
{
    // Используйте IntelliSense, чтобы узнать о возможных атрибутах.
    // Наведите указатель мыши, чтобы просмотреть описания существующих атрибутов.
    // Для получения дополнительной информации посетите: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Используйте расширение live server для vscode, если не принципиально нужно использовать launch.json

Comment: Спасибо помогло.

Comment: Рад помочь, советую ещё добавить в настройках (Ctrl + Shift + P > Settings Json) строчку, он отключит надоедливые сообщения "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true